# How to make third party SDK for Xamarin? (like Facebook SDK)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with bluetooth device with using Xamarin.forms. (PCL Project)

It's great platform and many great developers participate it. 
I love it.

I have a question, let's say, I have to do porting third party library(SDK) from each native SDK for Xamarin. (ex-facebook / Of course I know there is facebook SDK for Xamarin already. It's just for example.)
What documents should I look?

In my actual case, I have to make app that uses DFU OTA to nordic bluetooth mcu. Nordic company gave to their developer native code(iOS and Android) for that.
Now I have to convert or use it on Xamarin.forms.

I learned dependency services and it works great. 
Should I use dependency services?

Comment: You'll need to create a bindings project for each native SDK. Check out these docs: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/ for Android and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/. Once you've got the native SDK working with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, then a dependency service could help you.

Comment: @DylanS Thanks for your help! It seems right answer. ;)

Comment: @DylanS If company gave to their developer their SDK in a state of source code (not library package), should I make it as native library package and try as you said. right?

Comment: So you have the source code instead of the compiled library? I would think it will be easiest to compile it to a native library as normal, then use bindings as described in those articles.

Comment: @DylanS Yes and I got it. Thanks again Dylan.